# How do I install same version of ruby as different names with rvm?

Tags: rvm

After I installed a version of ruby with rvm, I noticed that some minor configuration issue on installation process. So I wanted to try to install with another configuration options, but I don't want to spoil the installed ruby at all.
So I just to attempt to backup the installed ruby before `rvm reinstall`.

```
(cd .rvm/rubies && mv ruby-1.9.3-p194 ruby-1.9.3-p194.org)
```

In my case, reinstallation fixed the issue, I didn't rollback ruby. So, I don't know this can work.
Are there any clean or correct way? Just for future references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can install [named rubies](https://rvm.io/rubies/named/):

```
rvm install 1.9.3-test1 [options]
```

and after it worked set it as default:

```
rvm use 1.9.3-test1 --default
```

or reinstall the original `1.9.3`, named rubies are useful especially for testing compilation flags or patched rubies:

```
rvm install 1.9.3-performance --patch falcon
```

Comment: Thanks mpapis. This must be what I asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can also have different gemsets with the same version using

```
rvm create gemset projectname
```